# How to setup Collision to state change?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to connect a "collision and mouse" sensor to an "and" controller to change a state and make a sound. The sound works upon collision but the state change doesn't happen...

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How can I make it change states?

Comment: Ensure both events occur at the same time